# Error Handling in VBS third party program like SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, vbscript, error-handling

I have to develop a WinCC Visual Basic Script management application. In this application I read an XML archive, and after that I put the information in a SQL database through a SQL INSERT query.

My problem is that I don't know how to do the error handling to view the SQL errors in VBScript `MsgBox` for example.

Activating the error handling with `On Error Resume Next` and after the evaluation of these errors with  `If Err.Number <> 0 Then ...` the errors produced in SQL Server don't appear in VBScript.

Comment: As always, for help with your code: show your code. How *exactly* do you insert into the SQL database? What do the errors look like?

Comment: Is it the VB error you are trying to get or SQL Server (if it is SQL Server)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get SQL Server error, You can use stored procedure with transaction to insert data into table:

```
create procedure dbo.InsertTable (
 @param1 nvarchar(80)
,@param2 nvarchar(80)
,@error_text nvarchar(400) output)
as
begin
begin tran
        begin try
                insert into YourTable (column1, column2)
                values (@param1, @param2)
        end try
        begin catch
                    set @error_text = error_message()
                    rollback
                    return
        end catch 

commit
end
```

Now You will get eventually error from the output parameter `@error_text`

```
declare @error_text nvarchar(400)
exec dbo.InsertTable 'Value1','Value2', @error_text output

select @error_text
```